# JQGRID Performance issues

Tags: performance, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

[image][image]My Jqgrid is freezing after 500 rows, page is blocking and if rows exceeds 1000 or 1500 then one browser alert is coming and saying that "long time to execute script .. do you wanna stop or continue.. " I am in no mans land can you please check my code and suggest me.. Am I doing any wrong.

```
one more issue is Why my loading GIF image and page stuck until all rows loaded?


$(document).ready(function ()
{


  GetTrackOrdersData();
```

});

```
   var searchFilter = {};
   searchFilter.REFERENCE = "%";
   searchFilter.INVOICENOR = ""; 
    searchFilter.PRODNAME = "ALL"; 
     searchFilter.ORDSTATUS = "WIP"; 

  ------etc ------



   function GetTrackOrdersData()
    {
 var param = JSON.stringify(
    {
        'searchFilter': searchFilter
    }); //This function is from JSon2.js
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "TrackOrdersNew.aspx/GetTrackOrdersData",
    data: param,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (mydata)
    {debugger;
        var mydata = $.parseJSON(mydata.d);
        if (mydata != null && mydata.length == 0)
        {
            $('#divgrid').hide();
            $('#gbox_list1').hide();
            $("#jqgridWrapperdiv").hide();
            alert('No Records');
        }
        else if(mydata != null)
        {
            var i = 0;
            for (i; i <= mydata.length; i++)
            {
                jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
            }
            if (i > 0)
            {
                $('.ui-jqgrid-title').text('Track Orders (' + (i - 1) + ')');
            }
            $("#jqgridWrapperdiv").hide();
            $('#divgrid').show();
        }
    },
    error: function (mydata)
    {
        alert("Some thing went wrong because of network. Please reload the page. Code:100T"+mydata.responseText);
        $('#divgrid').hide();
    },
    complete: function ()
    {
        $("#jqgridWrapperdiv").hide();
    }
});
```

}

```
   function bindGrid()
    {
      jQuery("#list1").jqGrid(
        {
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['Customer', 'Delivery', 'TrackNo','Ref', 'JobNo', 'Type', 'Product', 'Status',
        'EntryDate', 'Scheduled', 'Invoiced'           
    ],
    colModel: [
    {
        name: 'CUOH_CUST_CD',
        index: 'CUOH_CUST_CD',
        width: 100,
        classes: 'pointer'
    },
    {
        name: 'CUOA_DEL_CUST_CD',
        index: 'CUOA_DEL_CUST_CD',
        width: 69,
        classes: 'pointer'

    },
    {
        name: 'CUOH_TRAK_NO',
        index: 'CUOH_TRAK_NO',
        width: 70,
        classes: 'pointer'
    },
    {
        name: 'CUOH_SOURCE_REF',
        index: 'CUOH_SOURCE_REF',
        width: 70,
        classes: 'pointer'
    },
    {
        name: 'CUOH_JOB_NO',
        index: 'CUOH_JOB_NO',
        width: 60,
        classes: 'pointer'
    },
    {
        name: 'CUOH_ORDER_TYPE',
        index: 'CUOH_ORDER_TYPE',
        width: 65,
        classes: 'pointer'
    },
    {
        name: 'CUOL_DESCR_LOC',
        index: 'CUOL_DESCR_LOC',
        width: 155,
        classes: 'pointer'
    },
    {
        name: 'Status',
        index: 'Status',
        width: 100,
        classes: 'pointer',
        cellattr: function (rowId, value)
         { 
                // additional parameter of cellattr: rawObject, cm, rdata are optional
                if (value.indexOf("ompleted")!=-1) 
                {
                    return ' class="bcolor"';
                }
         }
    },
    {
        name: 'CUOH_ENTRY_DATE_TIME',
        index: 'CUOH_ENTRY_DATE_TIME',
        formatter: 'date',
        formatoptions:
        {
            srcformat: 'd/m/Y',
            newformat: 'd/m/Y'
        },
        width: 77,
        classes: 'pointer'
    },
    {
        name: 'CUOH_SCHEDULE_DATE',
        index: 'CUOH_SCHEDULE_DATE',
        formatter: 'date',
        formatoptions:
        {
            srcformat: 'd/m/Y',
            newformat: 'd/m/Y'
        },
        width: 84,
        classes: 'pointer'
    },
    {
        name: 'CUOH_INVOICE_DATE_TIME',
        index: 'CUOH_INVOICE_DATE_TIME',
        formatter: 'date',
        formatoptions:
        {
            srcformat: 'd/m/Y',
            newformat: 'd/m/Y'
        },
        width: 72,
        classes: 'pointer'
    }],
    //multiselect: true,
    //rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    //pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
    //rowList: [],        // disable page size dropdown
    //pgbuttons: false,     // disable page control like next, back button
    //pgtext: null,         // disable pager text like 'Page 0 of 10'
    //viewrecords: true,    // disable current view record text like 'View 1-10 of 100' 
    rowNum: 10000,
    sortorder: "asc",
    caption: "Track Orders",
    gridview: true,
    //shrinkToFit: true,
    loadui:"block",
    loadonce: true,
    rownumbers: true, //Displays Row number Column
    onSelectRow: function (rowId)//ondblClickRow
    {
        var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(rowId);
        var trackingNo = rowData['CUOH_TRAK_NO'];
        RowClicked(trackingNo);
   }     
});
```

}

C sharp:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string GetTrackOrdersData(TrackOrdersFilterData searchFilter)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginName"] == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
    string val = string.Empty;
    DataSet ds = GetTrackOrders(searchFilter);
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        val = DataTableToJSON(ds.Tables[0]);            
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Are you using pagination to limit the number of results you are passing to the grid?

Comment: @Mark - No pagination

Comment: Wouldn't this be an example where you SHOULD be using pagination? It sounds like you are giving the grid too much data (depending on what work you are doing on the grid data)

Comment: @Mark - I am loading the grid on page load as well as when he clicks on Search button after entering search filters...I am not using pagination.

Comment: Maybe I am not being clear, why CAN'T you use pagination to reduce the amount of data the grid is being requested to display?

Comment: @Mark - How to do that, I am inner joining 5 tables and getting the result..The Stored Proc takes time to execute, then for each page click it takes too much time.. correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are doing on the back end, what you should be doing is only passing a "page" of data to your end user.  What good are thousands of results to a user, only displaying a "page" or a subset of the data will allow your user to view a reasonable amount of information and then you do not have to pass so much data to your jqGrid that you are timing out the browser.

Comment: For example one customer searched for orders and Stored Proc returned 1500 records. Then how I have to send page by page to front end? what is the logic? Pls let me know